# How to contribute images to Google Maps in bulk?

Tags: google-maps, google-places

I am interested in contributing my images to Google Maps. I have quite a few of them (few thousands). However, I cannot find any satisfactory method to do it. I find it time consuming and cumbersome to contribute images from the Maps, contributor page. Where you can only do it one by one, plus I have to find the images among others that I am not willing to contribute that live in my Google Albums account.

I wonder is there an API that allows me to upload images with an embedded location (e.g. GPS tag in exif) in bulk?

Or maybe there is a contributor method I am not aware of - like if I can create a photo album and somehow tell Google please use those images on a map, that would be grand!

Thank you for your help.